# PostGIS: spatial analysis of point layer SRID 4326 using UTM grid

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, utm, count

*Edited, as suggested*.

I've got a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table 'Datos'

```
ALTER TABLE datos ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY;
UPDATE datos SET geom = ST_MakePoint(decimallongitude,decimallatitude);
update datos set geom = ST_SETSRID(geom,4326);
CREATE INDEX idx_geom ON datos USING gist(geom);
```

I need to do some analysis by means of a UTM grid 10x10 km that I imported from a shapefile using QGIS. The table details are

[image: table described]

The table SRID is 25830, so I projected the table 'Datos' to SRID 25830 using

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('datos','geom',25830);
```

Now, I need to count points within the grid cells, but I only get "0" values in the count as if they don't overlap (but they do!). I've tried several combinations of queries based on

```
  SELECT utmcode, count(datos.geom) as count
  FROM grid 
  LEFT JOIN datos 
      ON st_contains(grid.geom,datos.geom) 
  GROUP BY utmcode;
```

What is wrong in all this? Projection issues, query syntax or both? How can it be fixed?

Comment: `count(point.geom)` should be `count(points.geom)`. Your code is working for me

Comment: check that the reprojected coordinates are in the valid range for the chosen UTM zone

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what results you do obtain.

Comment: @JGH yes, at least some of the reprojected coordinates fall within the valid range for the chosen UTM zone. But, you are right, I will check for another srid covering the whole area.

Comment: @BERA I've edited my question, since it isn't a problem with the name (I've checked). So, if the query works, is it a problem with the projection?

Comment: You should add the request to build your grid and points tables, maybe you did something wrong here ?